# how to get the dm text in instagram from selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, instagram

I want to get the text of the sender on my console, I tried beautiful soup for scraping but it didn't work. I had used several other features like XPath and different class names on selenium but not able to resolve this issue.

Here, is my code,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

myemail = "<username>"
mypassword = "<password>"
friendusernames = ["<>sender username"]
PATH = "C:/Chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
url = "https://www.instagram.com/"
driver.get(url)


usernamebox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'username')))
usernamebox.send_keys(myemail)
passwordbox = driver.find_element_by_name('password')
passwordbox.send_keys(mypassword)
loginbutton = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.Igw0E')
loginbutton.click()
print("Logging in")

dmbtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.xWeGp')))
dmbtn.click()

notificationsnotnow = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.HoLwm')))
notificationsnotnow.click()


for friendusername in friendusernames:
    searchuser = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.EQ1Mr')))
    searchuser.click()

searchuserbox = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.j_2Hd')))
searchuserbox.send_keys(friendusername)

time.sleep(3)
firstuser = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '/html/body/div[5]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div')
firstuser.click()


pressingnext = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.rIacr')))
pressingnext.click()


names = driver.find_element_by_class_name(
    '_7UhW9 > span').text

# names = driver.find_element_by_class_name(
#     '.xLCgt').text

# names = driver.find_element_by_class_name(
#     '.MMzanKV-D4').text

# names = driver.find_element_by_class_name(
#     '.p1tLr').text
# names = driver.find_element_by_class_name(
#     '.hjZTB').text

print(names)

time.sleep(1)
```

### I want this text on my console

[image]

How, can I do so??

Comment: Could you describe more details about "not able to resolve"?

Answer (score 1):

Since every page on the internet has HTML in it, I would inspect the page with right click and find out which tag belongs to the message in the chat, then I'd find the tag's XPath or class and finally get its innerText for retrieving the string.

Comment: Yes indeed you are correct, but I am getting an error. I used this line of code for text  `names = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/span').text
` and I recived this error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="react-root"]/section/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/span"}`

Comment: If you're sure the XPath is correct, it may be because the element hasn't loaded at the time you try to find it. Use [WebDriverWait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to wait for the element to load, and then obtain its value.